# How to import a class/function in google Colab from a .py file on google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import a class from a .py file which is stored in my google drive.

Initially, I have mounted google drive as follows:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then navigate into the destination folder using:

```
%cd "/content/drive/MyDrive/Autonomous_Driving/GRTP/clstm_lifelong/us1011/sgan-nsl"
!ls
```

It shows output like:

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Autonomous_Driving/GRTP/clstm_lifelong/us1011/sgan-nsl
checkpoint.pkl        __pycache__           utils_wcgan_decompose.py
loss.mat          trained_models
model_wcgan_decompose.py  train_wcgan_decompose.py
```

Now in that `model_wcgan_decompose.py` file of the drive there was some class named `highwayNet_d`, `highwayNet_g_compose`, `highwayNet`. Now I am trying to import the class  for my purpose using:

```
from model_wcgan_decompose import highwayNet_d
```

but it shows error like:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-256c2191a0a5> in <cell line: 9>()
      7 #import model_wcgan_decompose
      8 
----> 9 from model_wcgan_decompose import highwayNet_d
     10 
     11 

ImportError: cannot import name 'highwayNet_d' from 'model_wcgan_decompose' (/content/drive/MyDrive/Autonomous_Driving/GRTP/clstm_lifelong/us1011/sgan-nsl/model_wcgan_decompose.py)
```

Please suggest how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can open `some_file` of code with `codecs`, use `json` to `load` it, and make it `str`ing so we can `exec`ute `some_code_in_string`; the important part is that we change the `'execution_count'` in its `dict`ionary from `None` to `1` (or however many times we want it to `exec`ute the code).

So here in `'SomeClass.ipynb'` I have the following code:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'init {self.__class__.__name__}')
        self.foo = 0
SomeClass()
```

In another file, we can run:

```
import codecs
import json

some_file = codecs.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/SomeClass.ipynb', 'r')
some_file = some_file.read()
some_file = json.loads(some_file)
some_file['cells'][0]['execution_count'] = 1
some_code_in_string = ''
for code_in_file in some_file['cells']:
    for _code_in_file in code_in_file['source']:
        some_code_in_string += _code_in_file
        some_code_in_string += '\n'
exec(some_code_in_string)
```

Outputs:

```
init SomeClass
```

Now if `some_file` is `'SomeClass.py'` it's a bit trickier since we have to `find` where the first line of code actually begins:

```
import codecs

some_file = codecs.open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/SomeClass.py', 'r')
some_file = some_file.read()
some_code_in_string = some_file[some_file[some_file.find('https'):].find('"') + 3 + some_file.find('https') + some_file[some_file[some_file.find('https'):].find('"') + 3 + some_file.find('https')].find(' ') + 3:]
exec(some_code_in_string)
```

Outputs:

```
init SomeClass
```

Either way, the goal is to get `some_code_in_string` correctly formatted like:

```
some_code_in_string = '''
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        print(f'init {self.__class__.__name__}')
        self.foo = 0
SomeClass()
'''
```

so that we can `exec`ute it.